# How to get the photos off a Windows phone

Tags: windows, usb, file-transfer, usb-device

How can I see the photos taken with a Windows phone?

I'm used to simply plugging in a phone using an USB cable and being able to browse to the folder containing the photos.
In this case however, although the phone does appear to my computer as a browsable device, I can't find any files that look remotely like images!
All I see is this:
[image]

Did some searching on the Internet, but the only instructions I could find were how to connect the phone to a Windows computer. Apparently nobody else ever wanted to connect a Windows phone to a Linux computer.

In case it matters, my computer is running Debian 8 with KDE and the phone is running Windows 10 mobile.

PS There doesn't seem to be a tag "windows-phone" for whatever reason, only "iphone".

Comment: Did you find [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/367927/how-to-connect-nokia-lumia-520-to-ubuntu-12-04)?

Comment: @garethTheRed The instructions there seem to install a new file system which allows the computer to see the file structure on the phone. However, I can already see that. Plugging the phone in does get me a new device which I can browse through. So I'm not sure about the usability of installing that. Besides, I don't like installing software on my system from outside the official Debian repository. Trying to keep my system as GNU as possible!

Comment: I'm sure there are MTP tools in the official Debian repositories.  The instructions in the link in my previous comment simply install the required tools and also set up the `udev` to recognise the phone.  There is also bug report in the comments for the first answer that might be relevant.